# Merging [mail] and [email] tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Both [mail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail) and [email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) refer to the same thing, so they should be merged to [email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has now been completed.

All questions with the [mail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail) tag have now been converted to the [email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) tag and a synonym has been created.